# Can't upgrade Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade

When I try to upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 using `sudo apt upgrade`, the system returns the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtag1v5-vanilla : Breaks: libtag1-vanilla but 1.10-0ubuntu1~xenial0 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Looks like you added non-Ubuntu PPA or repository which provides packages that are *version-incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu. Disable the repository, and uninstall ALL packages from that source.

Comment: How could I identify the wrong repository @user535733?

Comment: Have you added so many?

Comment: @user535733 Not recently...

Comment: Look through /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*. That's where your sources are.

Comment: Ok, I've checked all my sources and they were all added a long time ago... Do you think one of them could be the problem @user535733?

Comment: Whatever source you added that provides `libtag1v5-vanilla` seems to be the problem, according to the error message. Use the command `apt-cache policy libtag1v5-vanilla` to determine which source provides it.

Comment: @user535733 I've used the command and the terminal returns the following: `libtag1v5-vanilla:
  Installed: 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
` But I can't still idenfity the problematic source...

Comment: Comments are intended to help you refine and improve your Question, not for conversation. Please edit your Question instead of burying important additional information in comments.

Comment: From your description, `libtag1v5-vanilla` seems to come from an Ubuntu repo, and looks fine after all. Try `apt-cache policy` on the other package in that error message: `libtag1-vanilla`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @user535733! Mixxx was the problematic source, as pointed out in the answer of @gene_wood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on when you posted your question (June 19, 2018), I suspect you have the [Mixxx PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mixxx/+archive/ubuntu/mixxx) installed.

RJ Skerry-Ryan ([@rustyryan](https://twitter.com/rustyryan)) released [Mixxx 2.1.1 on June 13, 2018](https://launchpad.net/~mixxx/+archive/ubuntu/mixxx?field.series_filter=xenial) which appears to cause this conflict.

An [old bug that relates to this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mixxx/+bug/1532631) has begun to get attention starting June 25, 2018 as this conflict has recurred.

Until this conflict is resolved in the Mixxx PPA, I recommend you exclude `mixxx` from upgrades by running

`sudo apt-mark hold mixxx`

Once you do that, your `sudo apt upgrade` should work. Later when this is fixed you can run

`sudo apt-mark unhold mixxx`

to re-enable updates for mixxx

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You're right, I had the Mixxx PPA installed. Now I've uninstalled it and I've tried with the one of Ubuntu Software and it seems to work well.